# spark sql: how to create sessionId for user-item

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I've got dataset like this:

```
|    item    | event       | timestamp |   user    |
|:-----------|------------:|:---------:|:---------:|
| titanic    | view        |     1     |    1      |
| titanic    | add to bag  |     2     |    1      | 
| titanic    | close       |     3     |    1      | 
| avatar     | view        |     6     |    1      |
| avatar     | close       |     10    |    1      |
| titanic    | view        |     20    |    1      |
| titanic    | purchase    |     30    |    1      |
```

and so on. And I need to calculate sessionId for each user for continuous going events corresponding to particular item.

So for that particular data output should be the following :

```
|    item    | event       | timestamp |   user    |   sessionId    |
|:-----------|------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:--------------:|
| titanic    | view        |     1     |    1      |   session1     |
| titanic    | add to bag  |     2     |    1      |   session1     |
| titanic    | close       |     3     |    1      |   session1     |
| avatar     | view        |     6     |    1      |   session2     |
| avatar     | close       |     10    |    1      |   session2     |
| titanic    | view        |     20    |    1      |   session3     |
| titanic    | purchase    |     30    |    1      |   session3     |
```

I was trying to use similar approach as described here [Spark: How to create a sessionId based on userId and timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525843/spark-how-to-create-a-sessionid-based-on-userid-and-timestamp) with window:

```
Window.partitionBy("user", "item").orderBy("timestamp")
```

But that just doesn't work because the same user - item combination might be in different sessions. For example see *session1* and *session3*.
And with that window they become the same session. 
Need help with another approach how to implement that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach that first generates a column of timestamp value with conditional `null`, uses `last(ts, ignoreNulls)` along with `rowsBetween` to backfill with the last non-null timestamp value, and finally construct `sessionId` using `dense_rank`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  ("titanic", "view", 1, 1),
  ("titanic", "add to bag", 2, 1),
  ("titanic", "close", 3, 1),
  ("avatar", "view", 6, 1),
  ("avatar", "close", 10, 1),
  ("titanic", "view", 20, 1),
  ("titanic", "purchase", 30, 1)
).toDF("item", "event", "timestamp", "user")

val win1 = Window.partitionBy($"user").orderBy($"timestamp")
val win2 = Window.partitionBy($"user").orderBy($"sessTS")

df.
  withColumn( "firstTS",
    when( row_number.over(win1) === 1 || $"item" =!= lag($"item", 1).over(win1),
      $"timestamp" )
  ).
  withColumn( "sessTS",
    last($"firstTS", ignoreNulls = true).
      over(win1.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
  ).
  withColumn("sessionId", concat(lit("session"), dense_rank.over(win2))).
  show

// +-------+----------+---------+----+-------+------+---------+
// |   item|     event|timestamp|user|firstTS|sessTS|sessionId|
// +-------+----------+---------+----+-------+------+---------+
// |titanic|      view|        1|   1|      1|     1| session1|
// |titanic|add to bag|        2|   1|   null|     1| session1|
// |titanic|     close|        3|   1|   null|     1| session1|
// | avatar|      view|        6|   1|      6|     6| session2|
// | avatar|     close|       10|   1|   null|     6| session2|
// |titanic|      view|       20|   1|     20|    20| session3|
// |titanic|  purchase|       30|   1|   null|    20| session3|
// +-------+----------+---------+----+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need. You are lifesaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need to count the number of "view" records cumulatively.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when event = 'view' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by timestamp) as session
from t;
```

Comment: well, not really. View events are optional. I guess my example misleads you.